# Context retrieved from cobra subcommand is empty

Tags: go, command-line-interface, go-cobra, cobra

I want to have a global timeout (set in the `rootCmd`) so I am setting it in my `rootCmd` as follows

```golang
ctxInit := context.Background()
timeout := viper.GetInt("timeout")
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctxInit, time.Duration(timeout)*time.Second)
defer cancel()
cmd.SetContext(ctx)
```

then in a subcommand

```golang
ctx := rootCmd.Context()
```

but `ctx` is `context.emptyCtx {}`

Am I doing sth wrong in terms of setting / retrieving the context?

edit

my `rootCmd` declaration

```golang
// rootCmd represents the base command when called without any subcommands
var rootCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:              "my-cli",
    TraverseChildren: true,
    Short:            "cli",
    PersistentPreRunE: func(cmd *cobra.Command, _ []string) error {
        var err error
        logger, err = logging.InitialiseLogger(*logLevel, *logFormat)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if err := viper.BindPFlags(cmd.Flags()); err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("error binding flags to %s command: %w\n", cmd.Name(), err)
        }
        if err := cloneMethodValidator(cmd); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if err := InitConfig(false); err != nil {
            logger.Fatal("ERROR initiating configuration:\n", err)
        }
        ctxInit := context.Background()
        timeout := viper.GetInt("timeout")
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctxInit, time.Duration(timeout)*time.Second)
        defer cancel()
        cmd.SetContext(ctx)
        return nil
    },
}
```

Comment: Works as expected: https://go.dev/play/p/0x3QcwxBITT I find it odd that you call cmd.SetContext, but then later rootCmd.Context(). Are you sure cmd and rootCmd are the same *cobra.Command?

Comment: Yes it is set in my `PersistentPreRunE` function, check my update

Comment: I am wondering whether is the call to `defer cancel()` that is causing the issue...

Comment: That's a separate issue. Calling cancel at the end of PersistentPreRunE is definitely incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Peter, cmd and rootCmd are not the same. Cobra document describes `PersistentPreRun(E)`:

> children of this command will inherit and execute.

So `cmd.SetContext(ctx)` is not setting the rootCmd's context, it's setting the subcommand's context instead.

Then in a subcommand, you can use:

```
ctx := cmd.Context()
```

Instead of `rootCmd.Context()`.